# What is the meaning of $<$ in a preorder?

Tags: soft-question, notation, order-theory

Let $(P,\le)$ be a preorder, i.e. $P$ is a set and $\le$ is a relation on it that is reflexive and transitive. In this context for myself I can find two interpretations for the symbol $<$

1) $a<b$ iff $a\le b\wedge a\neq b$.

2) $a<b$ iff $a\le b\wedge\neg b\le a$

At first sight 1) seems normal. But looking at the partially ordered set that serves as skeleton of the preorder I would prefer 2).

Are there any conventions in order-theory about this notation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the second.

(1) turns out to be a pretty bad relation; it's usually neither antisymmetric nor transitive!

You can fix (1) by changing it to $a \not\equiv b$, where $a \equiv b$ is defined to be $a \leq b \wedge b \leq a$.

Comment: Glad to hear that it is the second. I can write it also as $a\leq b\wedge\neg a\equiv b$.
I do not understand your remark about fixing (1). It not the same
as $\neg a\equiv b$.

Comment: @drhab: I mean the basic idea of (1) is correct if not the detail: if you use equivalence rather than equality, then you get the expression you wrote, which is equivalent to (2).

Comment: I understand now. Thank you.